# Infinispan default cache.get does not work

Tags: java, infinispan

I loaded default package from infinispan.org version 6.0.0.
Ran standalone.sh on CentOS release 6.3 and trying to access to it from java client using hotrod.

Scenario:

1. Put key value - there is log on server where said that element was added sucessfully
2. Get by key - **null returned**, there is log on server where said that element was not found by this key
3. GetBulk - **returned element**

Here is code that I use:

```
RemoteCacheManager cacheContainer = new RemoteCacheManager(new    ConfigurationBuilder().addServer().host(SERVER_HOST).port(SERVER_PORT).build());
RemoteCache<Integer, Integer> cache = cacheContainer.getCache();
Integer result = cache.put(key, value);
Integer value = cache.get(key);
Map<String, String> bulk = cache.getBulk();
```

- The same scenatio works perfectly if infinispan installed on windows.
- java version "1.7.0_45" (both, client and server).
- The same fault behavior occures no matter remote calls or local ones.
- If we call getBulk or keySet - returns data that we expect.
- Checked sended and recieved keys - they are equal.
- Checked jvm version, tried on different and equal ones.
- Tried using different keys and values: String, Integer, Custom objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason default cache used wrong Comparer. If instead default one try it with named cache, everything works fine.